# Hypothesis test for odds ratios

Tags: hypothesis-testing, logistic, r-squared, odds-ratio, bic

I have two possible exposure variables (A and B) for use in a statistical model predicting a binary health outcome.  I have fitted models with each variable separately and now know that one variable is a better predictor of my outcome based on a comparison of R-squared and BIC values. However, the ORs for the two variables are quite similar with overlapping confidence intervals.  The sample composition and size is the same for each model.

I would like to comment on whether the odds ratios are significantly different from one another. How can I do this?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to compare two odds ratios. Try looking at

[Statistical test for difference between two odds ratios?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1405/statistical-test-for-difference-between-two-odds-ratios)

Comment: In this case the 2 ORs are not independent, I'd say.

Comment: Hi - yes I did see the earlier post, but as a novice I need something with bit more explanation!

Comment: As pointed out above, can you assume independence?

Comment: I'm not sure. How would I evaluate that? Exposure A and Exposure B are correlated to some extent, but rho is about 0.5.