# Logistic Regression - Odds Ratio

Tags: logistic

I have the following two logistic regression models where the independent variables are the same for the two models:

```
logit(Brand1) = b0 + b1 x1 + b2 x2
logit(Brand2) = c0 + c1 x1 + c2 x2
```

I can't use multinomial logistic regression because the respondents can choose more than one brand (that is, Brand1 and Brand2 can equal 1 at the same time).

My question is, can I compare the odd ratios across the two models? If, for example I have odds ratio (Brand1,x1) = 3 and odds ratio (Brand2,x1) = 5, can I say odds ratio (Brand2, x1) is higher than odds ratio (Brand1,x1)? That is, can I say Brand2 is more likely than Brand1 to have characteristic x1?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's perhaps worth pointing out that you can use multinomial logit if you want to.  You just have to re-define the choices.  There would be 4 alternatives: {nothing,brand1,brand2,both}.  Now, the assumption of independent errors that MNL uses is pretty untenable for this choice space, so you should probably use Generalized Extreme Value (GEV) instead of MNL regression.

Answer (score 3):

You can certainly say that one odds ratio (OR) is higher than the other; it's another matter whether you can say it is statistically significantly higher. That question is answered in [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1405/statistical-test-for-difference-between-two-odds-ratios).

However, you have a misconception of what odds ratios are. If the $b_1$ is higher than $c_1$ it doesn't mean that brand 1 has more of characteristic $x_1$. It means that a one point increase in $x_1$ has a stronger relationship with brand 1 being chose than with brand 2 being chosen.